# Looking for a very simple Bash script for automated key press

Tags: linux, bash, key

I would like to write a very simple linux bash script that simulates the key-combination "ctrl+S" every 60 seconds and runs in the background.

Unfortunately I don't have any clue about Bash Scripts and couldn't find related topics. Could someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: runs in the background?? and what's going to receive those keystrokes?

Comment: Sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Are you simply trying to save a document every 60 seconds?

Comment: The script is just supposed to regularly save a google docs spreadsheet in the browser. The idea is to simply turn on the batch script, turn to the browser and let it run.

Comment: Google Docs spreadsheets are automatically saved as you type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use xdotool in a loop:

```
while sleep 60
do
  xdotool key ctrl+s
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for. How can I turn this into a batch file? Or simpler, how can I make this run?

Comment: it's not that simple. http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#keyboard_commands

Comment: Thanks that worked. For any other linux-noobies like me looking for a similar solution, first install xdotool. Then simply create a text file containing the code from above and save it as a ".sh" file. Then, make this file executable, this can either be changed in the terminal or simply in the properties of the file. Finally, run the script in the terminal using "./", e.g. "./script.sh" .

Answer (score 0):

> The script is just supposed to regularly save a google docs spreadsheet in the browser.

This is unnecessary. Google Docs spreadsheets save themselves automatically anyway.