# Mac bash script - automate right arrow pressing every 2 minutes

Tags: bash, macos

Using Mac 10.11 version. Trying to write a bash script to automate "right arrow" press every two minutes. Could someone help please?

Background: Have a deck. To move to the next page, every time i need to click right arrow. So trying to eliminate "manually pressing of right arrow" every two minutes with the above script.

Already tried as suggested on [Looking for a very simple Bash script for automated key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664643/looking-for-a-very-simple-bash-script-for-automated-key-press), but no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: when you say "deck" - are you referring to powerpoint?

Comment: Maybe Applescript is easier: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript

Comment: Deck means ... its html pages, and need to press "right arrow" every time to move to the next page. i never used apple script, so no idea as how to create one though i m used with bash script

Comment: It seems to be that xdtool can solve your problem. Did it not work?

Comment: Indeed, unless your "deck" application is reading keypresses on standard input (which basically rules out every application with a GUI), Bash seems like the wrong tool for this task.

Comment: @blackpen: `xdotool` won't work on regular Mac applications (no X11; they run on Darwin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which application you are trying to automate, this should do what you are asking.

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e \
'tell application "System Events"
    repeat
        key code 124
        delay 120
    end repeat
end tell'
```

If you want to run this from Script Editor, remove `osascript -e \` and the single quotes at the beginning and the end of the script.

Comment: Thank you user556068 and realy appreciate your quick and correct response. As i m trying to automate the html pages navigation in "Safari", i just updated your script as below and it works fine.             #!/bin/bash
osascript -e \
'activate application "Safari"
tell application "System Events"
    repeat
        key code 124
        delay 002
    end repeat
end tell'